# XML request in PHP NuSoap - "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I'm using NuSoap within PHP to connect to an API.

At the minute, I'm just simple trying to send over an example XML string provided by the company who provides the API, however I'm receiving a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error.

I've queried this directly with the company but they've said that when they use the XML they've provided, as well as other clients, they aren't having any problems.

The XML I'm trying to send is:

```
![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Service>
  <Name><![CDATA[Demo]]></Name>
  <Description><![CDATA[Demo Service]]></Description>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Nodes>
    <Node NodeType="Start" NodeID="5" Description="">
      <!-- Comments can be included -->
      <MandatoryProperties>
        <Property Name="MaxLength" Value="0"/>
        <Property Name="EnableSpeedDial" Value="False"/>
      </MandatoryProperties>
     <OptionalSettings/>
      <Branches>
        <Branch Name="Continue" NodeID="20" Description=""/>
      </Branches>
      <DynamicBranches/>
      <DynamicProperties/>
    </Node>
    <Node NodeType="DeliverCall" NodeID="20" Description="Home Phone">
      <MandatoryProperties>
        <Property Name="DestinationNumber" Value="01132211444"/>
        <Property Name="RingDuration" Value="60"/>
      </MandatoryProperties>
      <OptionalSettings/>
      <Branches>
      </Branches>
      <DynamicBranches/>
      <DynamicProperties/>
    </Node>
  </Nodes>
</Service>]]
```

The response I'm getting is:

```
Response:
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 15:47:16 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 2.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Connection: close
```

I've used http://www.validome.org/xml/validate/ to validate the XML as I'm not experienced with XML and this is one of the few times I've had to use it, so I'm not going to be on the ball at picking up any syntax errors, but the error the validation tool is providing is:

[image: XML Error]

I've checked that there's no whitespace leading or trailing on the XML.

Something I've noticed is that in the XML, it's setting the encoding to `utf-8`. However the encoding in my request seems to be `ISO` - although it doesn't look as though there are any special characters or anything in the XML string.

The request data:

```
POST /dev/aspapi/api.asmx HTTP/1.0
Host: www.xxxxx.com
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: "https://www.xxxxx.com/ASPAPI/ValidateService"
Authorization: Basic bWVkaWFoYXdrOm1lZGlhaGF3aw==
Content-Length: 2127
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could spot anything wrong with this!

Full connection script:

```
<?php

require_once('./nusoap.php');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

$client = new nusoap_client('http://xxx.xxx/api.asmx', 'wsdl');

$client->setCredentials('xxxxx', 'xxxxx'); 
$client->response_timeout = 120;

$err = $client->getError();

if($err) {
    echo 'ERROR<br /><pre>' . $err . '</pre><br />';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<strong><em>Sucessfull connection</em></strong><br /><br />";
}

$proxy = $client->getProxy();

$proxy->setHeaders('<soap:Header><AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns="https://www.xxxxx.com/aspapi"><Token>xxxxx</Token></AuthenticationSoapHeader></soap:Header>');

$xml = '
![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Service>
  <Name><![CDATA[Demo]]></Name>
  <Description><![CDATA[Demo Service]]></Description>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Nodes>
    <Node NodeType="Start" NodeID="5" Description="">
      <!-- Comments can be included -->
      <MandatoryProperties>
        <Property Name="MaxLength" Value="0"/>
        <Property Name="EnableSpeedDial" Value="False"/>
      </MandatoryProperties>
     <OptionalSettings/>
      <Branches>
        <Branch Name="Continue" NodeID="20" Description=""/>
      </Branches>
      <DynamicBranches/>
      <DynamicProperties/>
    </Node>
    <Node NodeType="DeliverCall" NodeID="20" Description="Home Phone">
      <MandatoryProperties>
        <Property Name="DestinationNumber" Value="01132211444"/>
        <Property Name="RingDuration" Value="60"/>
      </MandatoryProperties>
      <OptionalSettings/>
      <Branches>
      </Branches>
      <DynamicBranches/>
      <DynamicProperties/>
    </Node>
  </Nodes>
</Service>]]';

$result = $proxy->call('ValidateService', array('serviceXML' => $xml));

$err = $proxy->getError();
if($err) {
    echo 'ERROR<br /><pre>' . $err . '</pre><br />';
    echo '<strong>Request:</strong>';
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($proxy->request); echo '</pre>';
    echo '<strong>Response:</strong>';
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($proxy->response); echo '</pre>';
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<strong><em>Sucessfull connection</em></strong><br /><br />";
}
?>
```

The output of the above script:

```
Sucessfull connection

ERROR
HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 400 Bad Request (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

Request:
POST /dev/aspapi/api.asmx HTTP/1.0
Host: www.xxxxx.com
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: "https://www.xxxxx.com/ASPAPI/ValidateService"
Authorization: Basic bWVkaWFoYXdrOm1lZGlhaGF3aw==
Content-Length: 2127

<TOKEN IS HERE IN OUTPUT>
![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Service>
  <Name><![CDATA[Demo]]></Name>
  <Description><![CDATA[Demo Service]]></Description>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <Nodes>
    <Node NodeType="Start" NodeID="5" Description="">
      <!-- Comments can be included -->
      <MandatoryProperties>
        <Property Name="MaxLength" Value="0"/>
        <Property Name="EnableSpeedDial" Value="False"/>
      </MandatoryProperties>
     <OptionalSettings/>
      <Branches>
        <Branch Name="Continue" NodeID="20" Description=""/>
      </Branches>
      <DynamicBranches/>
      <DynamicProperties/>
    </Node>
    <Node NodeType="DeliverCall" NodeID="20" Description="Home Phone">
      <MandatoryProperties>
        <Property Name="DestinationNumber" Value="01132211444"/>
        <Property Name="RingDuration" Value="60"/>
      </MandatoryProperties>
      <OptionalSettings/>
      <Branches>
      </Branches>
      <DynamicBranches/>
      <DynamicProperties/>
    </Node>
  </Nodes>
</Service>]]

Response:

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Fri, 24 Jan 2014 16:28:39 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET 2.0
MicrosoftOfficeWebServer: 5.0_Pub
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Connection: close
```

**Additional Info**

Still no luck as of yet, the output of the debug string can be found at http://pastebin.com/hF3DYGWP

Comment: Try changing this `![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` to this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` and remove `]]` from the end of the xml because with the `![CDATA[` at the beginning and `]]` at the end the xml is not well-formed

Comment: @elitechief21 it's essential that the XML is wrapped with `CDATA` (according to the company providing the API)

Comment: The creator of the API has a testing portal which allows you to validate an XML string - when I put my XML string into the validation tool within their portal, it returns a success. So it's definitely something to do with how I'm sending it over.

Comment: That doesn't sound right...you use <![CDATA[..]]> to specify textual data that shouldn't be parsed by the xml parser. Having `<![CDATA[` outside of the root element of the xml is not well formed and makes no sense because you're basically telling the parser not to parse any of the xml

Comment: Regardless of the well-formedness of the xml, could you post the code you have that is doing the upload?

Comment: @elitechief21 Like I say I'm fairly inexperienced with XML so I wasn't aware that's what CDATA does. However, the XML will not work on the API without surrounding the string with the CDATA as is done in the example.

Comment: @elitechief21 that's been added. I've also added the output of the script.

Comment: Try putting `<` before ![CDATA and `>` after `]]` in your xml string and see if that does anything, also remove the return in your xml string before `<![CDATA` so that your code reads `$xml = '<![CDATA` rather than `$xml = '`.  Not sure if this will make a difference or not but it's worth a try

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those made a difference!

Comment: I've added a link to a pastebin which has the output of `$proxy->debug_str` - hopefully someone can spot something which I don't seem to be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the headers.

The `<soap:Header>` opening & closing tags were causing the `HTTP Error 400 "Bad Request"`

```
$proxy->setHeaders('<soap:Header><AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns="https://www.xxxxx.com/aspapi"><Token>xxxxx</Token></AuthenticationSoapHeader></soap:Header>');
```

Should be

```
$proxy->setHeaders('<AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns="https://www.xxxxx.com/aspapi"><Token>xxxxx</Token></AuthenticationSoapHeader>');
```

Comment: I have similar problem during consuming c# webservice which is https based. I am getting HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 400 Bad Request. I think I have also header problems but according to implement your solutions I have no token.