# NuSoap returning status 400 - "Bad Request"

Tags: php, xml, nusoap

I posted this question a few days ago: [XML request in PHP NuSoap - "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337162/xml-request-in-php-nusoap-http-1-1-400-bad-request)

However I've filled the first post with probably too much information.

In a nutshell (for elaboration read the link above) I'm sending XML which has been validated by a tool provided by the API creators, but when I send a request to the API I receive the `Unsupported HTTP response status 400 Bad Request` error.

The output of `soapclient->debug_string` can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/hF3DYGWP

I personally cannot identify where this is going wrong.

Is there anything in the `debug_string` output that anyone can see which is the point of failure for this error?

Alternatively does anyone have any previous experience with this error in NuSoap and can shed some light as to where the problem was occurring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML request in PHP NuSoap - "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337162/xml-request-in-php-nusoap-http-1-1-400-bad-request)

Comment: Please update the original question rather than duplicating it with less information.

Comment: My original question... but I don't believe it's in the XML like in my prev. question.

Comment: Still better to update your old question instead of leaving it unanswered

Comment: Fair enough - didn't want to remove the existing content of the previous question in case it was related to the XML, I only posted this question to focus on the non-XML side of it, as like stated above the XML is successful when running it through the validation tool. Feel free to close if this isn't an acceptable question...